# How can i configure Box2D to work with Code::Blocks and mingw?

Tags: mingw, codeblocks, box2d

I tried many tutorials, but i can't get to work latest Box2D (2.3.1) with Code::Blocks and mingw.

I tried with this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AaM74Bol07A), but it's related to Box2D 2.2.1 and cmake.
Now, in the latest Box2D source there are not CmakeList files.
Haven't found too prebuilt Box2D libs suitable for mingw.

Any hint?
Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

This post was posted 3 years ago, but I had same issues since 1 month. So I propose an answer. If you encoutered the same problem you must not download the source file of Box2D from the github main page (https://github.com/erincatto/Box2D). You have to download the release zip file available here : https://github.com/erincatto/Box2D/releases.
This zip file contains tthe CMakeList files.

Comment: Thank you very much. Really appreciated